# Javascript - Store the response of a POST request in a variable

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have been trying to store the result of a POST request into a variable. I am coding in Zapier

```
let numero= input_data["numero"]
let data = {element: numero, elemento: "www.link.it" }

fetch("url", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})

.then(function(res) {
  return res.text();
})
.then(function(body) {
  console.log(body);
  var output = {rawHTML: body};
  callback(null, output);
})
.catch(callback);
```

Pretty new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this has much to do with Zapier. It is just orfdinary Javascript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) api

But you could for example do something like this:

```
let responseBody;    
fetch("url", {
method: "POST",
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
body: JSON.stringify(data)
})

.then(function(res) {
     responseBody = await res.text();
   })
  .then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
        var output = {rawHTML: body};
        callback(null, output);
  })
    .catch(callback);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Now I get the response like this: "{"success":true,"contact.id":111,"expireDate":"31/01/2022"}"

Do I have a way to separate each field?

Comment: @Bebbus can you mark the answer as "accepted answer" and upvote it please. Yes you can than accees each filed like ... responseBody.expireDate